# ionic2 set a page before ionic2-starter-sidemenu

Tags: ionic2

i downloaded the ionic2 starter sidemenu template, now it is showing homepage as first page with sidemenu which is set in app.component.ts as below

```
 rootPage: any = Home;
```

i'm planning to set my newPage as first page, there should be no side menu, from which i can navigate to the home page by clicking a button,

i added a page `'NewPage'` already but no idea about where to set this page.

my ionic version  : rc5

Answer (score 0):

Just change the root page to your new page:
    rootPage: any = NewPage